# Easy way to fill up pandas column based on values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns like this:

```
      a   b   c
0      1  1  10
1     2  12  10
2    16  13  10
3      9 16  10
```

In column `c` I would like to have the maximum of the 3 numbers in each row, so It should look like this:

```
      a   b   c
0      1  1  10
1     2  12  12
2    16  13  16
3      9 16  16
```

I could do this with for loops, but I was wondering if there is any  simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `df.max(axis=1)`

```
In [1807]: df['c'] = df.max(axis=1)

In [1808]: df
Out[1808]:
    a   b   c
0   1   1  10
1   2  12  12
2  16  13  16
3   9  16  16
```

---

Or, `assign` to return new dataframe

```
In [1812]: df.assign(c=df.max(axis=1))
Out[1812]:
    a   b   c
0   1   1  10
1   2  12  12
2  16  13  16
3   9  16  16
```